Calculating estimatedItemSize for FlashList component in UI with Multiple Feeds
I'm working on a user interface where I have multiple feeds to display using a FlashList component. My challenge lies in determining the optimal value for the estimatedItemSize property of the FlashList. How can I accurately calculate this value to ensure smooth performance while accommodating the variability in item sizes across different feeds?
I've experimented with setting the estimatedItemSize property to various values based on rough estimates of the average item size across different feeds. However, I've encountered performance issues such as scroll lag or incorrect item rendering.
I was expecting that by adjusting the estimatedItemSize property accurately, the FlashList component would efficiently render items without sacrificing performance, even with the variability in item sizes across different feeds. However, my attempts haven't yielded the desired results, and I'm seeking guidance on how to approach this issue effectively

If you're confused between two values, the smaller value is a better choice. https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage#estimateditemsize
